# xinit changing display size of my guest OS on vm

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, virtualbox, xorg

I installed a Debian OS on a vbox vm, but when I try to initiate a xserver with xinit to load my wm it reduces the screen size, I have a video size configured on grub to 1920x1080, but when I start xinit it goes to like 800x600, it's driving me crazy, I created a Xorg config changed the monitor values but doesn't work, I also created a 11-monitor file that doesn't already exist on `usr/share/X11/xorg.config.d` but doesn't worked too, I'm without any clue, I'm running a Debian 10 without GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a xterm through `xinit` and used `xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1980` and fixed the problem.